# How to perform this animation using canvas?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I am creating rotating planets by projecting a 200x100 bitmap on a sphere. Since this projection
is costly for an animation, I hacked an array with value-pairs ["pixel address in sphere projection image", "what pixels of original bitmap goes to that address"].
To just transfer them quickly with no math.
I end up with 16008 values, which represent the 8004 pixels we need to draw a circle (representing a sphere), on
a 100x100 canvas - planets always have radius 50 and I scale them later.
Now, to rotate a planet, all I have to do is to "shift" the second item of the pair by 1 pixel for a very slow rotation, and
higher values for a the illusion of faster rotations. I end up with this bottleneck:

```
    for (var i=0;i<16008;i+=2)
    {
        //the planet object has a canvas holding its texture, and 
        //the texturePixels array is the data of that texture after
        //a getImageData() of that texture canvas. finalPixels is
        //the pixel data for the final planet on screen projected image.
        locationInTexture=valuePairs[i]+planet.angle;//angle increases by 4 cuz each pixel is 4 rgba values
        locationInProjection=valuePairs[i+1];
        finalPixels[locationInProjection]=planet.texturePixels[locationInTexture]
        finalPixels[locationInProjection+1]=planet.texturePixels[locationInTexture+1]
        finalPixels[locationInProjection+2]=planet.texturePixels[locationInTexture+2]
        finalPixels[locationInProjection+3]=255; //alpha isnt relevant
    }
```

I also made the variables global to accelerate things. But it is still slow. My problem might
be that I should minimize DOM access, but I am accessing the pixel data in 2 canvases thousands
of times, and my guess is these don't behave just like normal 'arrays', though I might
be wrong in this case of simple array items reading/writing. The alternative seems to be to do this:
1-at load, get texture pixel data in a normal array instead of the one inherited from the canvas (is this relevant?)
2-get final pixel arrangement to a new normal array, instead of to the final planet display canvas directly.
3-create an image from that last array data and drawImage on the planet display canvas, and done, assuming
the (create image+draw it on final canvas) would be faster.

Or maybe we can even create a canvas with the sphere directly from the normal array data? Or using images
would be cheaper than canvases? How do I do this? Help please.
Thanks in advance :)

P.S. A screen can have tens of planets+moons when showing a solar system. I decided to ask before embarking
on an "img instead of canvas" approach, and find later that that is not the problem.

Comment: Could you include at least the calls to getImageData in your snippets (and even lore is welcome), these are likely the true botlleneck and it's not clear why you'd need them anyway. It sounds you don't draw anything more than this ImageData so keeping a single ImageData should be enough. You could gain a very little by using an uint32 view and set a pixel in one call ratjer than 3, but if you are really getting the pixel data at each frame this won't fix a thing.

Comment: Hi, and thanks. The getImageData is performed when a texture is loaded from the server, and only then, and the added as a variable to the planet object, which is from now on manipulated at the pixel level - the finalPixels array. You mean I should load these into a common array not linked anyhow to the canvas itself, and access this data from there?

Comment: I mean you should show a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe look into ThreeJS: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=planet#webgl_gpgpu_protoplanet